# Transfer addition of drag and drop in XAML to decorator - DevExpress

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, devexpress

Right now I have sth. like that in XAML:

```
        <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <managers:DragManager x:Name="DragManager" AllowDrag="True" AllowDrop="True" >
                <dxg:GridDragDropManager.DragElementTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate />
                </dxg:GridDragDropManager.DragElementTemplate>
            </managers:DragManager>
        </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

And I would like to remove that part from XAML and put it just to decorator.

Before I had

```
        AddMasterViewDecorator(new LineupGridMasterViewDragDropDecorator(this.DragManager));
```

now I tried with

```
        AddMasterViewDecorator(new LineupGridMasterViewDragDropDecorator());
```

And Constructor like

```
public LineupGridMasterViewDragDropDecorator() : base(new DragManager() {
   AllowDrag = true, AllowDrop = true, 
   DragElementTemplate = new System.Windows.DataTemplate() }) { }
```

`DragManager` is class I built but it inhereted from `GridDragDropManager`
and the problem is not hidden in this class because with XAML it's working.

How to deal with that problem?
Any tips?

I was searching on Devexpress documentation but I didn't spot anything interesting

New idea

```
public LineupGridMasterViewDragDropDecorator(LineupDataGrid lineupDataGrid) : base(new DragManager())
    {
        DragManager.AllowDrop = true;
        DragManager.AllowDrag = true;
        BehaviorCollection Behaviors = Interaction.GetBehaviors(lineupDataGrid);
        Behaviors.Add(DragManager);
        Behaviors.Attach(lineupDataGrid);
    }
```

but still not working :(

Comment: What is your actual problem? Which part is not working?

Comment: Drag and drop not working after changes and remove part form XAML
I think that it's connected with that Grid is not passed some way to decorator or sth like that, but I'm not sure